# Set cookie "currenttime" using javascript

Tags: javascript, video, cookies

I need help to know how to update value cookie "currenttime" using javascript.
I want to set current time of displaying movie. I use videojs (http://www.videojs.com/) and there is a function to get current time, which looks like this:

```
 var whereYouAt = myPlayer.currentTime();
```

But I don't know how to set this value to cookie.  I try this:

```
videojs("video1").ready(function(){
  var myPlayer = this;

  function setCookie(cvalue) {

    document.cookie = "cookiessss" + "=" + cvalue;
}
var whereYouAt = myPlayer.currentTime();
setCookie(whereYouAt);
});
```

But it doesn't change value of cookie during playing movie.

Answer (score 0):

This will only execute once. You can add an event listener for `timeupdate` which will fire as the video progresses.

```
myPlayer.on('timeupdate', function(){
  var whereYouAt = myPlayer.currentTime();
  setCookie(whereYouAt);
});
```